# How to asynchronously initialize resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I have `Task<ISomething>` that should be shared between all client threads. Also I have class `Worker` that is created once per request - `services.AddScoped<Worker>()`.

What is the correct way to initialize `ISomething` in my async code without constructing it multiple times?

If resource is under construction (calling webservice) other requests should wait asynchronously until it is complete and then continue. Also locking is not an option AFAIK. Is `AsyncLazy` good idea?

Answer (score 0):

A task can be awaited as much times as you need to.

In this particular case, because the task will be completed most of the time, `ValueTask<T>` would be a better choice.

I don't mention the particulars of creating `ISomething` but you can inject `ValueTask<T>` in most DI containers.

Comment: What if I need `Dictionary<string, Task<ISomething>>`? If I use concurrent dictionary there is possiblity, that task will be loaded on one thread and awaited on the other, so bad things may happen.

Comment: What bad things can happen in ASP.NET with this that would not happen any way?

Comment: For instance building ISomething would require DbContext, which was already disposed because the other thread ended and all dependencies were disposed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it looks to me that you are completely lost. Try posting come code to see if we can help more.